# AWS codepipeline may receive multiple s3 trigger events. How to delay queued codepipeline s3 trigger events until first process complete/successful?

Tags: amazon-s3, queue, aws-codepipeline, eventtrigger

Given a scenario where there is an S3 event trigger that starts an AWS codepipeline and updates existing ami's for multiple resources with new code; I need the codepipeline to run one event trigger at a time until it the codepipeline completes successfully successfully.

There is the potential that I could have multiple S3 event triggers that call the pipeline before it completes.

Assuming this is a scenario where I could somehow queue the event's, but start the next one after the previous event trigger is somehow notified that it completed successfully?

Any recommendations or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apologies.  This is not an issue with my code as much as how do I queue triggers (SQS?) such that the next trigger does not execute until the first codepipeline completes successfully and not queue the next trigger if the first one fails.  

Maybe this is not the right place to ask this question?